# Issue on Adding Animation To Cart Arrow on Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to properly animate the `.fa` classes? As you can see the animation works fine on clicking on each button but is not affecting to other buttons. For Example if you click on `Action A` and then click on `Action B` the arrow on `Action A` still is in previous state.

```js
$(".dropper").on("click", function(){
 //$('.dropper').find('.fa').removeClass('css-chevron-down').addClass('css-chevron-right');
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('css-chevron-right css-chevron-down');
});
```

```css
.css-chevron-down{
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.css-chevron-right{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6 "><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action A <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:left; margin-left:200px;"><div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action B <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write some code to bring the arrow to its original state, when the dropdown closes. The event you need for that is `hide.bs.dropdown`. The following piece of code will do the trick:

**Code:**

```
$("body").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
  var i = $(e.relatedTarget).find(".fa");
  i.removeClass("css-chevron-down").addClass("css-chevron-right");
});
```

Also, be sure to check out the following snippet to see live how it works.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(".dropper").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('css-chevron-right css-chevron-down');
});

$("body").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
  var i = $(e.relatedTarget).find(".fa");
  i.removeClass("css-chevron-down").addClass("css-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.css-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.css-chevron-right {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action A <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left; margin-left:200px;">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropper" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action B <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```